# Excel number sequencing based on flag

Tags: excel, windows, excel-365

I'm trying to create a formula for automatic number sequencing to help manage work.
I am working with a Category Flag, which is divided into 3 categories A, B, C, where the next alphabet is nested within the previous alphabet.

Within the A category, I want the Category B numbering to increase with each instance of B; and reset for next A category.
Please see attached image if clarification is needed.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I can't figure out the "Category B Numbering" formula to help automate this.
I have an IF statement which would cause the numbering to reset if the previous cell was blank, but I'm not able to grasp the IF statement to maintain the same number until next instance of Category B.

My current statement: =IF(previous_cell<>"", **PART I AM STUCK WITH**, 1)

If someone can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

For Cat A:

```
=IF(C2="A",SUM(A1,1),A1)
```

For Cat B:

```
=IF(C2="A","",IF(C2="B",SUM(B1,1),B1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was that simple...